# How can I export a report of selected changesets with Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, report

I would like to export a list of changesets in a "report"-like format, with the author, comment, and files changed (just the filenames, not the contents).

I'm using TortoiseHg on Windows. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of format do you want? Use `hg log` with a template. Mercurial has extensive support for customizing output, and it's very nicely [documented](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html) in the mercurial book.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that this had template support. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this problem (like many others) with Powershell. I generated an HTML report based on the patch files that Mercurial can export.

It's certainly not perfect, but it works well enough. The typical disclaimer applies, use this at your own risk, I am not responsible for what happens if you run this, etc etc.

Here's the code:

```
function Generate-PatchReport([string]$loc)
{
    $patchFiles = ls $loc -Filter "*.patch"

    $html = @()
    $html += "<html><head><title>Diff Report</title><style type=`"text/css`">body,table{font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt}
table{border-collapse:collapse;margin:10px}
p{margin:0}
thead{font-weight:700}
td{border:1px solid gray;padding:5px}
.bin{background-color:#eee}
.add{background-color:#dfd}
.chg{background-color:#ffd}
.rem{background-color:#fdd}
hr{height:1px;background-color:#999;border:none;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px}</style></head><body>"

    foreach($patch in $patchFiles)
    {
        $lines = gc $patch.FullName;

        # Get checkin notes
        $null, $null, $username = $lines[1].Split(' ')
        $datestamp = $lines[2].Split(' ')[2]

        $date = Get-Date -Year 1970 -Month 1 -Day 1 -Minute 0 -Hour 0 -Second 0 -Millisecond 0
        $date = $date.AddSeconds($datestamp)

        foreach($l in $lines)
        {
            if(!$l.StartsWith('#'))
            {
                $note = $l
                break;
            }
        }

        $html += '<p><strong>Note:</strong> ' + $note + '</p>'
        $html += "<p><strong>User:</strong> $username</p>"
        $html += "<p><strong>Timestamp:</strong> $($date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")) UTC</p>"

        # Generate file reports
        $html += "<table><thead><td>Operation</td><td>File</td></thead>"
        for($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.Length; $i++)
        {
            if($lines[$i].StartsWith('diff'))
            {
                $html += "<tr>"
                $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $filename = $lines[$i].Split(' ')

                if($lines[$i+1].Contains('Binary file'))
                {
                    $html += '<td class="bin">% Binary</td>'
                }
                elseif($lines[$i+1].Contains('/dev/null'))
                {
                    $html += '<td class="add">+ Add</td>'
                }
                elseif($lines[$i+2].Contains('/dev/null'))
                {
                    $html += '<td class="rem">- Remove</td>'
                }
                else
                {
                    $html += '<td class="chg">&bull; Change</td>'
                }
                $html += "<td>$filename</td>"
                $html += "</tr>"
            }
        }

        $html += "</table><hr />"
    }

    # Finalize HTML
    $html += "</body></html>"

    # Write the file to the same folder
    sc $html -Path ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($loc, "PatchReport.html"))
}
```